# External IP not responding after Kubernetes deployment

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am new to Kubernetes and was testing a sample deployment. The following is the output from the kubectl get services command. After I deployed the application thru a deployment yml it completes successfully and the pods are provisioned. Now I go to `EXTERNAL-IP:80` but I don't get a response and the page keeps spinning.

```
NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
demotest2               LoadBalancer   XX.X.XX.XX     XX.XXX.XXX.XX   80:30904/TCP   35m
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: just test your service locally, your selectors are off, probably

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem? Or you still need more help? Please give updates.

Comment: In my deployment file I used "app: nginx1" instead of "run: nginx1"  in the selector spec and the same was used in the Services spec as well.

Comment: It does not matter what key value you used, it works only when you use the same key value in both deployment for the pods and the service. Finally, do you solve the problem with the answer? If yes, please accept it.

Comment: I changed the deployment yml and deployed in my local and it failed and the following is the pod event. do you know why this is happening?

Warning  Failed     12m (x4 over 14m)    kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "kubernetes-django": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for kubernetes-django, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the message you provided, there are two possible reasons. **One** is that the pod of your deployment does not run well. It means your image which hosts your application does not work as you want. For this, you need to check if your image can work well locally. Another one is that the `demotest2` service does not route the request to the pod of your deployment. For this, you need to check if the `selector` of the service was set correctly for your pod.

**For example:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginx1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: test1
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: nginx1
```

In this example, the pods of the deployment use the label `run: nginx1`, so you need to set the `selector` of the service as `run: nginx1`.

Comment: How can I edit the yaml file, or where can i find it? thank you